# Zend Framework SQL update query

Tags: sql, entity-framework, zend-framework, sql-update

How would I write this SQL the Zend Framework way?

```
UPDATE register 
SET balance = (balance + 10) 
WHERE added_date > 1259944184 ;
```

I can't find any examples of this on Zend's website or the web.

Do I need to use "`Zend_Db_Expr`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

acording to zend framwork documentation

use this

```
$data = array(
    'balance'      => 'balance + 10'
);

$n = $db->update('register ', $data, 'added_date > 1259944184');
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. I got it working using an sql query like this:
$stmt=$this->_db->query(' UPDATE '.$this->_name.' SET balance = (balance + \''.$difference.'\') WHERE added_date > \''.$addedDate.'\' ');
  $numAdded=$stmt->rowCount();
  echo '<br>'.$numAdded.' Rows Affected'; 
But I really want to use the fluid method of ZF.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
$data = array(balance => new Zend_DB_Expr('balance + 10'));

$db->update('register ', $data, 'added_date > 1259944184');
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try this... make sure your model is ready.

`$table = new register();`

> This is the model class

`balance=balance+10;`

`$data = array(`
    `'balance'      => 'balance'`
 `);`

`$where = $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('added_date > '. 1259944184 );`

> You can use $where[] for multiple conditions

`$table->update($data, $where);`

[For more details follow link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.db.table.html)

Answer (score 0):

I used this to modify element order to top.
Code as follow from the table class extending Zend_Db_Table_Abstract:

```
$data = array('i_order' => new Zend_DB_Expr('i_order + 1'));

return $this->getAdapter()->update($this->_name, $data, "i_id != {$oCurrent->i_id} AND i_order < {$i_order}");
```